# text/x-scriptlet not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript

When I try to add a page using object tag as follows:

```
<object id=Trans type=text/x-scriptlet > <param name="url" value="xyz.html">
```

This will work in IE without any error but when I try to launch in chrome is not displays any data.  We are creating  an dynamic table inside that html file. Also when we use this we are not able to do copy the content displays in that object tag(table). Kindly tell me any alternative type or other way to load the html file. In html we are creating table via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Scriptlets are an experimental, non-standard technology that is only supported by Internet Explorer.

The standard way to load content from an external file with JavaScript is via the [the XMLHttpRequest object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest). You'll need to process the data in the response with JavaScript too.